# TRPC: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_def')

Tags: next.js, trpc.io

I'm using the T3 stack and whenever I try to query one of my controllers I get this type error on the server. On the client I'm getting `TRPCClientError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`. Any ideas?

Comment: You're probably tring to JSON parse something that isn't JSON. What you are parsing is an HTML.